# Tables showing in phpmyadmin but not query + more

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, forms, http-post

I'm still new to POSTING from an html web form with php to a database, but I think I've been able to piece together everything I need. But something is still missing and I don't know what.

I tested my connection and tables with:

```
<?php
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","#user","#password", "#database");
  if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
  }
  echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
  echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
  $test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM" $#database;
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $test_query);
  $tblCnt = 0;
  while($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $tblCnt++;
    #echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";}
    if (!$tblCnt) {
        echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
    } else {
        echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
    }
  mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I've tried 127.0.0.1 and an access host IP (RemoteMySQL) to no avail. My user has full permissions. I'm not aware of any other default security that could be hindering me.

I'm hosting with Bluehost, using MySQL and phpmyadmin. There are 2 tables in my database and they are found when I type "SHOW TABLES" in phpmyadmin. What am I missing? This is beyond my knowledge. I'm at my wits end...

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are missing one curly braces after else condition your code has error.

Comment: You're checking for an error after calling mysqli_connect, but not after subsequent mtsqli_ calls (which would reveal the problem)

Comment: The code is entirely copied from a template to check for a connection. I just removed the sensitive information and (just noticing) that I changed the SHOW TABLES line. Either way, it returns the same incorrect zero tables.

symcbean, can you specify what mtsqli_calls are and how they would help? I'm not sure if I'm correctly connecting to something wrong, or if the tables I have created aren't actually accessible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some problems in this line.

```
$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM" $#database; // Line 10
```

You don't have any variable named $database. And you have the symbol # that is not correct. # is used for comments ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php )

There is a space missing after FROM. This line should be

```
$test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $database;
```

Otherwise, the query generated would be "SHOW TABLES FROMDATABASE_NAME" which would trigger a SQL error.

Also, you have a curly brace missing after the while loop. Here is the full code corrected.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","#user","#password", "#database");
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
 }
 echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db 
 database is great." . PHP_EOL;
 echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;
 $database = "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE";
 $test_query = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $database;
 $result = mysqli_query($link, $test_query);
 $tblCnt = 0;
 while($tbl = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $tblCnt++;
 }
 // echo $tbl[0]."<br />\n";}
 if (!$tblCnt) {
     echo "There are no tables<br />\n";
 } else {
     echo "There are $tblCnt tables<br />\n";
 }
 mysqli_close($link);
 ?>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm still learning the proper way to represent code (and notes within it). That's the reason for the "#"s.

I think your code is the same as the template I found and used. It's still returning with no tables.

Comment: Oh sorry @StevenGuerrero . I've tried on a local environment, it should be better now. I've edited my answer with the correct code. 
In the mysqli_query, you were using a $connect variable that didn't exist, you should use $link instead. And I forgot a . (operator to concatenate) to use the database name in the query.

Comment: Don't forget to replace with the name of your database where I wrote "YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE" and in the line where you setup the connection :)

Comment: That did it! Thank you Laila!!

Comment: @StevenGuerrero You're very welcome ! Would you mind accepting the answer so that someone you might have a similar problem know this solution works ? :)